# Testing the presence of a predicate in SPARQL

Tags: rdf, sparql

I have the following RDF model:

```
@prefix : <http://test.com/#> .

:graph1   :hasNode   :node1 ;
          :centerNode   :node1 .

:graph1   :hasNode   :node2 .
:graph1   :hasNode   :node3 .
```

I want to run a SPARQL query in which if a `:nodeX` is related to a `:graphX` with a predicate `:centerNode` I return `true` (or some other indication) otherwise `false`; The result would look something like the following:

```
?n       ?g        ?centered
-----------------------------
:node1   :graph1   true
:node2   :graph1   false
:node3   :graph1   false
```

Is there a way to do this in SPARQL 1.0? if not, can it be done with in SPARQL 1.1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine `EXISTS` and `BIND` as follows in SPARQL 1.1:

```
PREFIX : <http://test.com/#>

SELECT * WHERE { 
  ?graph :hasNode ?node .
  BIND( EXISTS { ?graph :centerNode ?node } as ?isCentered )
}
```

Using Jena's ARQ, I get these results:

```
$ /usr/local/lib/apache-jena-2.10.0/bin/arq \
   --data predicate.n3 \
   --query predicate.sparql
---------------------------------
| graph   | node   | isCentered |
=================================
| :graph1 | :node3 | false      |
| :graph1 | :node2 | false      |
| :graph1 | :node1 | true       |
---------------------------------
```

Comment: Any idea how can this be done in SPARQL 1.0? We have a constraint under Oracle to use 1.0.

Comment: Hmm… I was thinking about this, and I'm not sure there's a solution that's quite as elegant. You can certainly run _two_ queries, one filtering out when `?graph :centerNode ?node` exists and one where it doesn't.  If I think of something better, I'll certainly update the answer.  The trouble is, it seems to me, that there aren't as many binding constructions (e.g, `BIND( … as … )`) in SPARQL 1.0.

Comment: Another option would be to add `OPTIONAL { ?graph :centerNode ?center . FILTER( sameTerm( ?node, ?center ) ) }`.  Then, for each result row, `?centerNode` is bound if and only if `?isCentered` would have been `true`.

Answer (score 4):

In SPARQL 1.0,

```
SELECT * { 
  ?graph :hasNode ?node .
  OPTIONAL{ ?graph :centerNode ?node1 FILTER sameterm(?node, ?node1) }
}
```

and ?node1 will be bound or not bound in the answers.
Cardinality is messy though.

OPTIONAL/!BOUND can do a sort of NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT * { 
  ?graph :hasNode ?node .
  OPTIONAL{ ?graph :centerNode ?node1 FILTER sameterm(?node, ?node1) }
  FILTER( !bound(?node1) )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly the purpose of ASK queries in SPARQL:

```
PREFIX : <http://test.com/#>
ASK WHERE { 
  ?graph :hasNode ?node .
  ?graph :centerNode ?node .
}
```

Comment: It is indeed, however I have a large WHERE query in which I need this 'ASK' information too.